# What is "Euclidean geometry, under Peano's axiom system"?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, peano-axioms

I read the following in the article on ["Primitive Notion"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_notion) on Wikipedia:

> Euclidean geometry, under Peano's axiom system the primitive notions
>   are point, segment and motion.

I could not find any more explanation there about "Euclidean geometry, under Peano's axiom system".
So I got confused about many points. What Peano's axiom system has to do with Euclidean geometry? What are the point, segment and motion in this axiomatic system?

Please provide some explanation and references on this topic. Is there any book, paper or article that discusses the topic "Euclidean geometry, under Peano's axiom system"?

Comment: The references under http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundations_of_geometry contain several relevant sources.